# How to get original error message from guava retryer?

Tags: java, guava, retry-logic

I have a Guava retryer around some code:

```
Retryer<Boolean> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder()
    .retryIfExceptionOfType(Exception.class)
    .withStopStrategy(5)
    .withWaitStrategy(exponential wait (10, 30, seconds)
    .build();

try {
   return retryer.call(myMethod);
} catch (ExecutionException | RetryException e) {
  throw new MyErrorWrapper(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

However, the only error message I get propgated to my main application is Retrying failed to complete successfully after X attempts. I understand this is because the guave retryer is throwing a RetryException once it hits the limit of 5 but is there any way to get th eoriginal error message that caused this back up to my main app?

Comment: Guava doesn't have a retryer.  What library are you using?

Comment: @LouisWasserman This one: https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying It's a feature [requested already in 2010](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/490) and on which your team has said they're experimenting on.

Comment: hi @OlivierGrégoire were you able to find a way to get the original message? I'm facing the same issue